# php shell_exec($cmd) do not run in a cronjob

Tags: php, exec, shell-exec, cyberduck

sorry for that (I believe) poor question, but google and other articles in this forum can't help me...

I'll run the a php script with following code in it:

```
    $cmd="duck  -u user_name -p pwd -parallel 1 -e overwrite -y --throttle 1024 --upload path to remote file absolute_path_to_local_file";
    $shellResponse=shell_exec($cmd);
```

This works well, when I call this php file in the browser. 
But it fails, when I call the script within a cronjob.

With a cronjob i get following errormessage:

```
sh:1: duck not found
```

I believe this can be a permissions problem, but I'm new in this area and do not know where I can set the permissions and what I have to do.

Can anybody please help me?!

Comment: Try using the absolute path to the application in your command. Does anything change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cron jobs do not get the normal PATH env variable that is usually available.

Try using the absolute path for the 'duck' command instead.

Example:

```
$cmd = "/usr/bin/duck ..."
```

To find the absolute path, you can type

```
which duck
```

on a normal command prompt