# Execute a shell script with PHP at a specific Time

Tags: php, linux, shell

This PHP code should start a shell script at the time saved in the `$start` variable and at the time saved in the `$end` variable. All Files are `chmod a+rwx` . It works on command line but not in `shell_exec()`, also the `$start` and `$end` variables are in the correct time Format `hh:mm`. I found this [other Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31332209/how-to-run-php-script-at-a-certain-time-using-at-command) in which someone had a similar Problem but nothing posted there helped me.

```
if ($_POST["device"] == "Ventilator") {
    $start = $_POST["start"];
    $end = $_POST["end"];

    if ($_POST["start"] != "0") {
        shell_exec('echo "/home/pi/IOT/gpio21high.sh" | at $start');
        echo "$start".
        "<br />";
    }

    if ($_POST["end"] != "0") {
        shell_exec('echo "/home/pi/IOT/gpio21low.sh" | at $end');
        echo "$end".
        "<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: start by enabling error reporting and looking at your logs. You may also want to add a few `else{}` and see where that goes.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199353/how-can-i-debug-exec-problems

Comment: the `echo "$start". "<br />";' gets executed every time, so 'else{}' is useless , but you are right in the logfile it said "You do not have permission to use at." . i gave the .sh and the .php file 'a+rwx' rights, do you have an idea what i was missing ?

Comment: i made a misstake while reading , the log files are old sry so thats not the problem

Comment: @mario i checked every answer from the post you linked and none of these worked

Comment: If you have no logs or debugging output, verify if anything got scheduled then: `atq`. Otherwise this isn't answerable I'd guess.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php shell\_exec($cmd) do not run in a cronjob](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46934471/608639)

Answer (score 0):

It could be a great idea to execute this as a Cron job, you can execute it at a set interval etc that way.

Hope this helps thanks,

Comment: I think it's not really suitable as cron job, as the script itself schedules "at" cronjobs.